# Where to put iTunesArtwork Image in PhoneGap Build Ad Hoc Project?

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, itunes, itunesartwork

I am not using Xcode to develop but rather HTML5stack with PhoneGap Build. I do not have a "Resources" folder but rather an "Image" folder. I understand that this file should not be included with my .ipa build for the [App Store Review](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html). But if I want my app Icon to show up in the iTunes Library under an Ad Hoc Developer certificate build, then which folder should I put the **iTunesArtwork** (512x512px with no file extension) file--in "Image" folder or at the root of the "www" folder with Icon.png and splash.png files?

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: No, never figured it out.